# How to fix 'ReactCommon/CallInvoker.h file not found' after manual upgrade from v0.61.5 to v0.63.3

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I had to manually upgrade react-native, because `nix react-native upgrade` failed.

After following the Upgrade Helper for v.0.61.5 -> v0.63.3, ive cleaned my build folder and tried to run the application, only to get a failed build

the error is:

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'ReactCommon/CallInvoker.h' file not
> found ->
> NativeToJsBridge.h

why is this happening? comment for additional environment/file information

Comment: Any luck resolving this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the `ios/` directory in your project.

Delete `Podfile.lock` and `Pods/` directory, then run `pod install --repo-update`.